# unintended gap between elements

Tags: html, css, firefox

i've looked briefly through similar questions but i could not find the answer i was looking for

I basically have

```
<nav>...</nav>
<div id=inner>...</div>
```

and there is a 29px gap between the elements only in firefox.  firebug tells me there both elements have 0 padding/margin and there is nothing in between them.  it works fine in IE (barring gradient problems/css3) and chrome.

this is the page in question

> http://www.jerseymicrowave.com/testing/index2.htm

thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `display: block;` from `nav:after`